# How can I remove mouse and key clicks from live audio?

Tags: recording, recommendations, noise-reduction, realtime, linux

I need to stream live audio from my desk while being able to use my computer at the same time. I have tried following the tips from [How do I remove mouse click noise](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/how-do-i-remove-mouse-click-noise) and [How to Reduce Keyboard and Mouse Clicks](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38829/how-to-reduce-keyboard-and-mouse-clicks), but I still get click noises in my audio stream, and I don't have a very large budget

Here is my setup:
I have one cardioid microphone that I position between my keyboard and myself. I also have a webcam with an actually pretty good microphone positioned on the far side of the keyboard, that picks up much more of the key clicking than the cardioid.

A solution could potentially use any of the second mic or directly processing the input events on my computer to potentially recognise keypresses, and either apply a filter specific to the keypress or just temporarily quiet the audio or something. Or it could work some other way, I don't know.

Whatever the program though, there are a few basic requirements I have:

- It needs to work in a linux environment.
- It needs to process audio in real time.
- It can't add more than 100 ms of latency.

An ideal solution would be one that I can use for free, but paid software is not completely out of the question as long as it doesn't cost too much.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to proceed in your case is to increase the signal to noise ratio as much as possible. Try a different location for the microphone - somewhere where is further away from the keyboard noise. Try speaking closer to the mic and use lower amounts of gain.

An software solution might not get you any satisfying results

Answer (score 0):

1. Position the microphone MUCH CLOSER to your mouth.
2. Use a "non-clicky" keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr Crowley notes, not all keyboards and mice have the same amount of clicking noise. You could install micro switches into a mouse that are 'clickless' (check that the mouse in questions has easily desoldered/soldered switches). Some keyboards have a soft action.